Methods for Transferring Incoming Calls and SMS from Android to iPhone
First of all, hello friends. My issue is briefly as follows: I want to transfer incoming calls to an Android device to an iPhone. I have two phones, one Android and one iPhone. What I want to do is instantly transfer incoming calls and SMS from the Android device to the iPhone and be able to make calls from the iPhone through the Android device. What I want is something that the devices already support (like Android Auto or CarPlay). I have several different methods in mind, but I haven't found an app or a method that can do what I mentioned. It could be done using one of these methods:

Incoming calls to the Android device can be transferred to the iPhone via Bluetooth.
If we use the Android device only as a tether and connect from the iPhone via Wi-Fi, I can make and receive calls and SMS over Wi-Fi (presumably VoIP) even when the iPhone is not registered. I can do this by getting a twin SIM card, but when the Android device connects to the phone network, the iPhone becomes inactive, meaning it only needs to connect to the network for internet like a mobile Wi-Fi.
The simplest solution, which I can't find, is to transfer incoming calls and SMS to my iPhone via a third-party application.
This request may seem strange to you, but unfortunately, if you don't register the device in Turkey (which costs approximately 1000 USD), you can only use the device with your SIM card for 8 months of the year.

